# Undefined Offset: 1 in Laravel 5 Due to Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-routing

I'm Getting this error with the route `add-site`.

`ErrorException in compiled.php line 7315: Undefined Offset: 1`

Here are the files...

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('add-site',['middleware' => 'auth',function()
{
    return view('dashboard.add_site');
}]);
```

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Session::has('sa_loggedin')==FALSE and !Session::has('sa_server_id'))
    {
        return "error!";
    }
    else
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know the error might be silly but I'm not getting it... I'm trying to solve this error since hours...

Answer (score 2):

You can remain simple with this sort of stuff

```
Route::get('add-site', function () {
   return view('dashboard.add_site');
})->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: Yeah, at that time I was new to laravel. I researched a lot and got the solution. You are correct, I was going complex.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('add-site',['middleware' => 'auth',function()
{
    return view('dashboard.add_site');
}]);
```

error is in this array

```
['middleware' => 'auth',function()
    {
        return view('dashboard.add_site');
    }]
```

>

```
    array('middleware' => 'auth',
    ?? => function()
            {
                return view('dashboard.add_site');
     }
)
```

There is no index to that function